# libgdx, how to check collision of randomly generated actors?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two groups of randomly generated actors, one is bullets second is enemies. And as of now I have no idea how to check collision of randomly genrated actors and remove the overlaped actors. I'm newby.

At least provide some pseudocode! Thanx in advance!!!

Comment: I suggest starting by looking at [`Rectangle.overlaps()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html#overlaps-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle-).

Comment: Actually I previously used Rectangle. Overlaps(), but I dont have any idea how to apply it on randomly generated actors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First ensure that your Actors are able to report their bounds:

```
public class Enemy extends Actor {

    Rectangle bounds;
    public Enemy() {
        bounds=new Rectangle((int)getX(), (int)getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    private void setXY(float pX,float pY) {
        setPosition(pX, pY);
        bounds.setX((int)pX);
        bounds.setY((int)pY);
    }
}
```

Then collect any Actors into ArrayLists:

```
//init lists
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

//add actors to lists
enemies.Add(new Enemy());
bullets.Add(new Bullet());
```

Now you can itterate though the lists and check for collisions:

```
for (int i = enemies.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Enemy enemy = enemies.get(i);
    for (int j = bullets.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        Bullet bullet = bullets.get(j);
        if(enemy.getBounds().overlaps(bullet.getBounds())) {
            //handle collision
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, I'm new here so can't give you +1 else you deserve it!!!

Comment: but a nested for() loop is terrible for performance - is this really the only way ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere This approach was chosen for its simplicity. If you are more concerned about performance then you might want to consider a [quad tree](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374).